# Drawing in a WPF App (.NET Core) throws a runtime error

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing

I'm trying to port a WPF graphics application to .NET Core.  I found a test case on the web, but it doesn't work with the latest (Preview) release of .NET core.
The program throws an exception on line 6.

Here is a screen capture of my Visual Studio 2019 screen:

[image]

The screen capture may be hard to read, so here is my code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Drawing;

using Brushes = System.Drawing.Brushes;
using Color = System.Drawing.Color;
using FontFamily = System.Drawing.FontFamily;
using FontStyle = System.Drawing.FontStyle;
using Image = System.Drawing.Image;
using Pen = System.Drawing.Pen;
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;

namespace TestGraphics {
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow:Window {
    private static void TestGraphics() {
      System.Drawing.Image image = new Bitmap(2000, 1024);
      Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(image);
      graph.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Azure);
      Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
      graph.DrawLines(pen, new Point[] { new Point(10, 10), new Point(800, 900) });
      graph.DrawString("Hello drawing from .NET Core :)",
                       new Font(new FontFamily("DecoType Thuluth"),
                                20,
                                System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
                       Brushes.Blue,
                       new PointF(150, 90));
    }
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      TestGraphics();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my ".csproj":

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="3.0.0-preview5.19224.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.6.0-preview5.19224.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I hope someone can suggest a fix for this problem.

Charles

Comment: I wouldn't call it a WPF Graphics application when it uses WinForms drawing primitives. Why is that?

Comment: I wasn't aware the System.Drawing only works in WinForms.

Comment: I does work in a WPF application, but it is hardly ever necessary to use it. WPF has its own set of drawing primitives.

Comment: O.k. so it should work in WPF.  So tell me why my program is throwing an exception on line 6?

Comment: Besides that the error message is about line 6 in MainWindow.xaml, check the InnerException.

Comment: I checked the checkbox nexy to PresentationFramework.dll and I got:
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
'The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestGraphics.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'

Comment: That is what you have already shown. That exception has an InnerException property.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released a cross platform library for .NET core to handle System.Drawing:

[System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common)

I haven't used it yet, but should do the trick.

Comment: I added <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.6.0-preview5.19224.8" />.  It did not help.